# How to use/call puppeteer script in laravel controller

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, puppeteer

I have a web scraper script that uses puppeteer. I want to run this script on the server then get the results in a json format and update my database. How can I call /run this script in a controller. I am using laravel 5.8?

Comment: You could just do `$result = shell_exec('node /path/to/my/script.js');` Depending on how you've set things up you may need to provide the full path to node as well or change the current working directory

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as:-

```
exec('node /var/www/html/mywebsite/public/puppet/puppet.js '.$param);
```

And can pass any param with it by giving space after puppeteer script location.